# Get DNS server from DHCP options without lease

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dhcp

I'm configuring dnsmasq, and need to know the IPs for the upstream nameservers. The DHCP server does set them via option 6 for DHCP clients, but the dnsmasq server does not use this DHCP server.

Is there a way that I can programmatically query the DHCP server for the list of DNS servers it *would* set? Right now I'm trying to craft a raw packet for use with netcat/socat, but this seems like something the DHCP client could do, if I could find the right set of parameters. The dnsmasq server is running Amazon Linux 4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64 with dhclient 'Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1'.

Comment: It's 6 years old, but perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056310/probe-dhcp-server-and-dump-received-dns-host-configuration) ?

Comment: Can you add it as an answer? I actually tried this, but the DHCP server is NAKing the requests.

Answer (score 1):

It's 6 years old, but perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056310/probe-dhcp-server-and-dump-received-dns-host-configuration)

He forked dhclient and created [DHCProbe](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/DHCProbe) to request a lease and dump the results.